# Suppose the quadratic covariation of process $X$ with $B$ is constant - then is $X$ linear in $B$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $X$ is progressively measurable with respect to the filtration of a Brownian motion $B$ and $L^2$. Suppose that $[X,B](T)=C$ for some real constant $C$, then is it true that $X$ is linear in $B$?

Because $X$ is $L^2$ we can use the martingale representation theorem to get that $$X(t)=f(t)+\int_0^t\phi(s) dB(s),$$

for some progressively measurable $\phi$.

Therefore the quadratic covariation is

$$\int_0^T \phi(s) ds=C.$$

If this is constant (independent of $B$), then is it true that $\phi(s)$ is independent of $B$? If not, what can we assume on $X$?

Comment: When you say constant are you meaning with respect to time (i.e. $[X,B]_T=[X,B]_S$ for all $S,T>0$) or something else ? In the former case unless mistaken $C$ must be $0$  as  $\phi \equiv 0$

Comment: @TheBridge I meant constant wrt the path

Comment: Sorry but what does "constant with respect to the path" mean formally ?

Comment: The quadratic covariation at time $T$ is a real valued functional on Wiener space. I want to know when that functional is a.s. constant.

Comment: Ok so you mean that $[X,B]_T(\omega)=C$ for any $\omega$

Comment: @TheBridge Yes, for a.a. $\omega\in \Omega$.

Comment: @TheBridge Eg, if we assume Malliavin differentiability of $\phi$ I think we might be able to get it. I don't have a proof of that, but something I've thought of

Comment: Well this is true indeed I think the fact taht X is adapted to the brownian filtration also entails that $\phi$ must be deterministic

Comment: @TheBridge Do you have a proof? Thank you for your time

Comment: @TheBridge for example let $\phi(t)=B(t)$ if $t\in [0,T/2]$ and let $\phi(t)=-B(T/2-t)$ for $t\in [T/2,T]$. Then the QC is constant wrt the path but $\phi$ is not deterministic.

Comment: I don't understand your martingale representation argument.  We have $[X,B](T) = C$ but you seem to be assuming $E[X(T)] = C$.  For instance, think about when $X=B$; then $[X,B](T)=T$ but $X$ is certainly not of the form $X(t) = T + \int_0^t \phi(s)\,dB_s$; the expected values don't agree.

Comment: I don't think that in your case the co-quadratic variation is constant for 2 different paths ... moreover if it were the case then X wouldn't be a linear in $B$

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry, the $C$ in the martingale representation has nothing to do with the $C$ in the covariation. The $C$ in the martingale representation should even have a $t$. Fixed

Comment: @TheBridge It is indeed constant (wrt the path) - it is the constant $0$.

Comment: Yes my mistake I overlooked the minus sign but now  you are fixed about your question as this counterexample shows a non linear in B process X that has constant coquadratic variation  unless mistaken

Comment: By the way the counterexample exhibited is quite "ad hoc", it does hold for time $T=1$ but only at this time.  I do not see how to generalize this more uniformly in time, maybe this is where we can get back on our fit to retreive the result you are looking for.

Comment: @TheBridge I am not quite fixed - I would like to know of a condition where this does hold. For example if $\phi(t)$ only depends on $B(t)$ and not the past it is true.